# How to carry out ArrayList implementation so as to store person details

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to implement an ArrayList which can hold like person records.  I can only do this so far:

---

**CODE**

---

```
import java.util.*;

class ArrayListDemo {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    System.out.println("Initial size of al: "
            + al.size());

    al.add("C");
    al.add("A");
    al.add("E");
    al.add("B");
    al.add("D");
    al.add("F");
    al.add(1, "A2");
    System.out.println("Size of al after additions: "
            + al.size());

    System.out.println("Contents of al: " + al);

    al.remove("F");
    al.remove(2);
    System.out.println("Size of al after deletions: "
            + al.size());
    System.out.println("Contents of al: " + al);
}
}
```

---

A member of this website told me to do the following, I really dont get how to get about doing that:

---

You do

```
ArrayList<Person> myList = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

and then you can repeatedly

```
newPerson = new Person("Bruce", "Wayne", 1972, "Gotham City");

myList.add(newPerson);
```

and you can access folks in the list by doing

```
int personNumber = 0;

Person retrievedPerson = myList.get(personNumber);
```

or even

```
for (Person someone : myList) {
   System.out.println(someone);
}
```

---

Any help as to complete a simple program utilizing the above points mentioned by that particular [stackoverflow member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217989/how-to-store-information-about-many-people-in-java) (ie. answer by Carl Smotricz) would be appreciated.

Thanks alot

Comment: My answer to your other recent post gives the skeleton of a Person class for this sort of thing. If you're having trouble, please ask for help with *specific* points rather than just asking for a complete program.

Comment: This is all basic Java. You need to work through a tutorial on how to write a class. Then take a look at collections, especially List and Map.

Comment: I was away. I will consider what Jon Skeet and starbkue has said.

Comment: It sounds to me as though you need a basic tutorial in Java programming ... and not an answer to a particular programming problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Go through this

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package sl4jdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class arrayTest {

    public static class Person{
        String name;
        String SSL;
        String Street;
        Integer age;

        public String getSSL() {
            return SSL;
        }

        public void setSSL(String SSL) {
            this.SSL = SSL;
        }

        public String getStreet() {
            return Street;
        }

        public void setStreet(String Street) {
            this.Street = Street;
        }

        public Integer getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(Integer age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Person(String name, String SSL, String Street, Integer age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.SSL = SSL;
            this.Street = Street;
            this.age = age;
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<arrayTest.Person>();
        persons.add(new Person("Bob", "FKJHHS87546", "WALLSTREET", 21));
        persons.add(new Person("Tom", "SEFSDF875463", "WALLSTREET", 25));
        for (Person person : persons) {
            System.out.println("Name : "+person.getName());
            System.out.println("SSL : "+person.getSSL());
            System.out.println("Street : "+person.getStreet());
            System.out.println("Age : "+person.getAge());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for bad style: Ignoring naming conventions for classes and variables, needlessly nesting classes, not making member variables private.

Comment: The plural of *person* is *people*, not *persons*.

Comment: this code was really helpful. Going to build up on that. Thks taher and Valentin for the edit

Comment: @TrueSoft Not really: see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/person-persons-people-peoples and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46294/correct-usage-of-persons-vs-people

Comment: @TrueSoft: People is a noun that can, from time to time, serve as a plural for person. However, persons is a word recognized by our own dictionaries.  Interestingly, the plural of people is peoples, as in "all the united peoples of this kingdom."  The thing about English is that one must distinguish between style and grammar.  Of the three valid plurals of octopus (octopi, octopuses, octopodes) the correct one to use is mainly only dictated by the style appropriate to the context.